# Can I use a custom section link which differs from the section heading?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using reStructuredText and Sphinx to write some documentation, but I may want to change my section headings in the future:

```
Some Title Which I May Want To Change
=====================================
```

For these section headings, Sphinx generates a link like `thepage#some-title-which-i-may-want-to-change`. This means that when I do change the name, any old links someone may have made will now be broken.

Can I use a custom link for the heading which differs from the heading text?

```
.. use-this-link:: perma-title
Some Title Which I May Want To Change
=====================================
```

With a link to `thepage#perma-title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Section headers](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) generate an [implicit hyperlink target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets) based on the heading text. What you want is the ability to use a custom hyperlink target; an [explicit hyperlink target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets). We can do that like this:

```
.. _some-title-which-i-may-want-to-change:
.. _perma-title:

Some Title Which I May Want To Change
=====================================
```

This combines a few features to do what we want:

- The `.. _perma-title:` adds an explicit hyperlink target to the heading. However, without this, the hyperlink generator ¶ will still use the old implicit hyperlink target. To solve this:
- The `.. _some-title-which-i-may-want-to-change:` is an explicit hyperlink target with the same reference name. The documentation states that this will "override any implicit targets having the same reference name."
- The `.. _some-title-which-i-may-want-to-change:` is positioned to be a "chained" internal hyperlink target, giving it a place to go. That means that if someone were to access `thepage#some-title-which-i-may-want-to-change`, they will also go to this heading.

With these changes, the hyperlink generator symbol ¶ will generate the `thepage#perma-title` link that you wanted.

Comment: This may work, but I wonder if there's a better method.